# why this .htaccess regular expression is not working?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a regular expression as below

```
http://www.abc.com/signup.php?id=2

RewriteRule ^signup/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ /signup.php?$1=$2 [L]
```

but this is not working? can any one help me.is there any thing to enable in the .htaccess file?

Comment: do you see a `/` after the `.php` in your sample url? I don't...

Comment: can you please give the correct one. i didnt understand?

Comment: Do the module mod_rewrite enabled?

Answer (score 2):

As you are passing also numbers, you should match them in regular expression as well:

```
RewriteRule ^signup/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ /signup.php?$1=$2 [L]
```

You might want to include other chars as well or rather use metaclass such as `\w`.

Comment: and what URL are you trying to rewrite into `http://www.abc.com/signup.php?id=2?`

Comment: Well if the URL is already like this, the webserver will handle it without any rewrites. If you want your application to send different URL, you need to change the application (and webserver with above rewrite will handle /signup/id/2 URLs).

Answer (score 0):

After edits, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(\d+) 
RewriteRule ^signup\.php$ /signup/%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^signup/([0-9]+)$ /signup.php?id=$1 [L]
```

That'll redirect `/signup.php?id=123` to `/signup/123` which will then be rewritten back to `/signup.php?id=123` (but not redirected).

Comment: why it is not working.i've tried both the answers but no one is working

Comment: You need to post what you're trying to rewrite from, what you're trying to rewrite to, and what is happening right now.

Comment: i have a link like http://abc.xyz.com/signup.php?id=2 and whenver user clicks on the url should convert to something so that the actual style of the url will change

Comment: That's not what rewrites are for. They're for taking the external representation of a URL and rewriting them to an internal representation your application will understand. They can be used for that, but it's a different approach. I'll update my answer.

Comment: is there any way to hide the id value from the address bar?

Comment: Look at my answer now. And no, you can't completely hide the ID if your application needs it. You can disguise mask it but changing the URL structure but you can't remove it.

Comment: oh god it is not changing at all.the url appearing as it is. is there any other method for this? :(

Comment: Gah - forgot rewrites only match the path. I'm giving it one last shot before I tell you to just handle this in code. Check the updated answer.

Comment: hmmmm ok leave it :( thank you for your help and others.it is not working.